# Where do I put code that I need to run on all web pages in Play Framework?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework

I apologize in advance for this somewhat ignorant question, but I have researched this as much as possible on my own over the last week. My last resort was to come here because I know the folks on stack overflow are the smartest out there.

I'm an ASP.NET guy who recently switched over to Play, per company mandate. I'm a little lost. MVC is new to me, and ORM scares me entirely.

I've walked through the tutorials on playframework.org, and while I was able to build a blog engine, I was just transcribing code from their tutorial into my own program, so i don't feel like I really learned anything.

Now I'm having to write a PLay version of a .NET website. So onto my question.

On each webpage in my play app I need to run some Java code that generates a huge HTML string and then spit that html string onto a label on the view somewhere. It's like a 100 line function, and it just ends up returning a string that I render out to the client. In my .NET websites I just put this in the "code behind" of my master page.

The problem is that my master page in Play has no code-behind. So where do i put all this java code that needs to execute on every page? I started looking at controllers, but it's not an object that I would forward to the render function, it's a 100 line function that does a bunch of logic and returns a huge string. I need this code on every screen, so it doesn't make sense to put it at the controller level, because then I'd have to pass it to "render" every time, and I have like 100 actions.

Which really begs the bigger question, if your code isn't a model and doesn't really make sense in a controller, where do you stick it in Play? Anyway, thanks in advance.

Cheers
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need this code on every screen, so it doesn't make sense to put it at the controller level, because then I'd have to pass it to "render" every time, and I have like 100 actions.

For these cases you can use the @Before annotation. In your controller:

```
@Before
public static void bigFunction() {
   String result;
   // Do a lot of stuff...
   renderArgs.put("yourLabel", result);
}
```

In your template you can access it now via:

```
${yourLabel}
```

Comment: He needs to also use raw: ${yourLabel.raw()} since the function returns pre-rendered HTML.

Comment: Also - the bigFunction should be made protected to prevent it from being exposed as an action.

Comment: I wouldn't object, but are you sure it's necessary? I get a 404 when accessing /bigFunction.

Comment: It's more of an issue if you use default routes (at either the controller or application level); e.g. try /Application/bigFunction. But it's also good to document that the method is for utility only - and never used as an action.

Comment: Thank you very much Marius. I was not familiar with "renderArgs.put()". Will this interfere with any other renders that get called in the processing pipeline for a given page load?

Comment: And yes you're right, Scott. In good old WebObjects all actions return a WOActionResult, thus making it clear what is an action and what isn't.

Comment: oh one more question, I've got a controller for each folder (set of views), but I need this code to run on all of them, so which controller do I add this "bigFunction" to?

Comment: You can put it in a base (abstract) controller and have your other controllers inherit from it. But yeah, this is where Scott's answer comes into play :)

Answer (score 0):

I think Marius has the answer that you're looking for in the short term. But IMHO, you would do well by your successor (or yourself a year down the road) if you took the time to grok the function and re-implement it correctly into MVC components. That is, put the data representation and manipulation stuff into a model, and the HTML generation stuff into a view tag or the main.html template.

Comment: I've considered this Scott, but this code is just a helper utility function, it doesn't have any state per se. I just need it to run every request. it would be an interesting model with only one property and a function for populating that property. Is this commonly done in MVC?

Comment: Most commonly you'd make a template that contains a minimal amount of logic. The advantage is that this looks more directly similar to the HTML you're generating (without all those out.println's). Then put the decision making stuff in your controller (or model) and set whatever renderArgs values the template requires. However, Play does let you create custom tags (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/templates#tags - scroll down to Custom Java Tags) for the exceptions...